# How the use the 'time' parameter in INPUT when using ::SendInput

Tags: winapi

The Windows ::SendInput function receives an INPUT object, which has a 'time' parameter.  I could not find any examples on the net that utilizes this parameter.  The MSDN documentation isn't helpful either.

I'm actually trying to animate a mouse movement across the screen, and I think this parameter can achieve that.

Anybody knows how to use it?

Comment: It is not for delayed playback. [It is for backdating input](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/11/01/10364713.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It equates to the time the message is sent (as reported by `GetTickCount()`), and is equivalent to the value that the `GetMessageTime()` function retrieves when processing messages.